# Possible cyclic definition when extending a base that is generic in stubs but not at runtime

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Here is the minimal example that I can come up with:

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

from queue import Queue


if TYPE_CHECKING:
    queue_base = Queue['Foo']  # line 7
else:
    queue_base = Queue


class Foo(queue_base): ...


b = Foo()

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    reveal_type(b)  # line 18

print(b)
```

This runs ok (with regular python) but mypy gives errors:

> this.py:7: error: Cannot resolve name "queue_base" (possible cyclic definition)
>
> this.py:7: error: Cannot resolve name "Foo" (possible cyclic definition)
>
> this.py:18: note: Revealed type is 'this.Foo'

If I define `Foo` class as `class Foo(Queue['Foo']): ...` then it works in mypy but throws an error at runtime:

> TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Pretty much as is described under [Using classes that are generic in stubs but not at runtime](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#using-classes-that-are-generic-in-stubs-but-not-at-runtime), the difference being that I'm trying to pass the "self-type" to the generic. Can this be done?

---

This is the simplest example I could come up with, but in practice the classes are from Django (managers and querysets), so it makes more sense then a "queue of self".

Answer (score 0):

Well, this seems to work:

```py
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    class _QueueBase(Queue['Foo']): ...
else:
    class _QueueBase(Queue): ...


class Foo(_QueueBase): ...
```